# Как исправить ошибку: cairo.h: No such file or directory?

Tags: perl, gui, gtk

Как исправить ошибки при установке *perl-gtk3*?

[Лог консоли](http://pastebin.com/xgUP2Ar2), последние строки:

```
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "C:\Strawberry\perl\lib\ExtUtils\xsubpp" -nopr
ototypes -typemap "C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\ExtUtils\typemap" -typemap "build\cairo-
perl-auto.typemap" -typemap "cairo-perl.typemap"  Cairo.xs > Cairo.xsc && "C:\St
rawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e mv -- Cairo.xsc Cairo.c
gcc -c  -I. -Ibuild -I/srv/win32builder/fixed_364/build/win32/include/cairo -I/s
rv/win32builder/fixed_364/build/win32/include/freetype2 -I/srv/win32builder/fixe
d_364/build/win32/include       -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IM
PLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -
s -O2     -DVERSION=\"1.105\"   -DXS_VERSION=\"1.105\"  "-IC:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\
CORE"   Cairo.c
In file included from Cairo.xs:10:0:
./cairo-perl.h:17:19: fatal error: cairo.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'Cairo.o'
  XAOC/Cairo-1.105.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Cairo'.
```

Comment: Установить (и/или настроить) cairo.

Answer (score 1):

ошибка — `cairo.h: No such file or directory`.

чаще всего подобная ошибка означает, что не установлены требующиеся заголовочные файлы.

в данном случае — для *cairo*. инструкции по установке для разных операционных систем можно получить, например, [на этой странице](http://cairographics.org/download/).